# Custom fonts via CSS 3 - how to make it look the same across browsers?

Tags: fonts, css

I'm trying to use the Delicious font via CSS 3's @font-face property, but unfortunately the rendered text looks pretty indifferent across browsers. Are there some tricks or general guidelines to make it look the same?

Also, it seems that there's no AA in TTF's, but with OFT there is. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are looking for, but go through this `@font-face` syntax by fontsquirrel - [link](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
    src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
    }
```

But delicious is only available in .otf